# Ant Design Table Render calls function continuously

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a  table in ant. The table column has user Ids. I am using a function to take the id and look up the user's name. For some reason, react keeps calling the function continuously.

In the render function I define the Table Column:

```
const columns = [
      {
        title: "Members",
        width: "200px",
        dataIndex: "members",
        key: "members",
        render: members => this.getMemberAvatars(members)
      },
```

Here is the function being called:

```
  getMemberAvatars(members) {
    let membersAvatars = [];
    members.forEach(userId => {
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => membersAvatars.push(doc.data().displayName));
    });
    console.log("getMemberAvatars is running");
    return members;
  }
```

In the console (continuously):

```
"getMemberAvatars is running"
```

It runs over and over. I've tried even a simple function that just returns a console.log - same thing. For some reason my function inside 'render:' are called over and over vs. just once.

Comment: what means continuously?

Comment: Meaning, the function runs over and over. I clarified above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends on number of elements in your data**,

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-easley-hu1tt

Here, since my data array has 4 elements, it executed only 4 times. (check console below code box)

For example if you want to use it for only particular userid

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-robinson-hg5o5

Comment: This is helpful. So I must have an issue with the data source. Must be how I am fetching firebase data. Thank you.

Comment: Turns out the parent component was re-rendering. Once I fixed that, this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach an element in your render, let's say

```
render: (userId) => (
 <Button
  onClick={this.getUserName(userId)}
 >
 </Button>
}
```

```
const getUserName = (userId) => (event) => {
  // Do process here
  console.log(userId)
}
```

Comment: I need this to run without user action (ie button). I'm rendering data.

Answer (score 0):

You get the data in record:

```
render: (record) => (
 <Button
  onClick={this.getUserName(record)}>
 </Button>
}

getUserName = (record) => {
  console.log(record.userId)
}
```

Comment: I need this to run without user action (ie button). I'm rendering data.